# Give permission to acces /var/run/docker.sock on Synology NAS

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, nas, docker

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/) to setup traefik properly on my DS918+.
Everything seems to work normally but I can't actually launch it because

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/traefik/logs?follow=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&tail=100&timestamps=1: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I have tried `sudo chmod +rwx docker.sock` with the user that I'm using to launch the docker but to no avail.

How should I solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
sudo synogroup --add docker <userid>
sudo chgrp docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Once you have done this, **you must log out from the shell** for the changes to take effect (at least if you were logged in as *<userid>* when running the commands).

Comment: It's worth to mention that `synogroup` (`v2003-2023`) supports both UID and username as the argument for `-add` or `--memberadd`. Yet, it does not check whether UID or username exists prior adding. Thus, please be careful with username letter-case too. Also, the command does not support removal of members, and only `--member` is an option which rewrites the whole member list it seems.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual dock implementations, either you use docker as root (or with sudo) or you add the authorized user to the `docker` group (the socket is group-writable):

```
ll /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Apr 19 16:13 /var/run/docker.sock=
```

AFAIK this is not done by default because having docker rights in practice gives you root access, so beware.

Comment: Thks for your reply. I indeed start the  docker with sudo but it still gives me that error. How does one add a user into a group on synology?

Comment: On Synology to add user to a group the command is: ```sudo synogroup --add <group> <user>```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to run the `docker` command via `sudo`

```
docker exec -it homeassistant bash
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/container                                   s/homeassistant/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

And then

```
sudo docker exec -it homeassistant bash

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
homeassistant:/config#
```

Interesting point is that I should enter the my password. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the `root` password.