Docker permission issue, in Synology NAS
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/traefik/logs?follow=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&tail=100&timestamps=1: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

I'm using synology docker, and at some point I started needing sudo privileges to use docker, and I don't know what I did wrong.
Even after reinstalling the container manager, the same problem occurs. What is the solution?
The solution in the link below does not work.
https://superuser.com/a/1769106/2387314
DSM version: DSM 7.2.2-72806 Update 1

@Ramhound In the Synology OS, there were no commands, groupadd, usermod ...
